# Uncaught afterRender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputDate' [a.split is not a function]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Erecord}" var="obj">
          <div style="{!(obj.Typee=='DATE')?'display:block':'display:none'}">
              <ui:inputDate displayDatePicker="true" label="{!obj.Fieldd}" labelClass="{!obj.ApiNamee}" value="{!obj.Valuee}" change="{!c.onBoardChange}"/>  
          </div>
    </aura:iteration>
```

This is the code I am using in lightning. **Erecord** is the wrapper list which is having wrappers for a field's information such as

- Fieldd : is having label name of a field.
- Valuee : is the value of that field.
- Apinamee : is having apiname of the field.
- Typee : is the type of the field.

So if I am iterating the wrapper like this, its showing error on console log.

**Uncaught afterRender threw an error in 'markup://ui:inputDate' [a.split is not a function]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the following:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EASdQAO